# Git: What happens if you don't commit before closing?

Tags: git, git-bash, git-commit

I'm surprised I couldn't find a more thorough explanation of the nature of staging/commits so I'm asking myself. I'm new to GitHub (and don't have Bash downloaded on this computer, so I'd rather have people answer).

Specifically, let's say you are working in a project directory with GitBash. You make some basic changes and save. Without staging or committing anything, you close all your applications. What happens to the changes you made? Do they get wiped or do changes stay? I guess the same question applies for if you committed your things but then exited out.

Are "commits" stored in a folder somewhere? Is the "staging area" just a temporary Bash thing or is there a physical folder for that too?

Would you have to re-commit changes if you exit out?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You can figure it all out just by performing experiments.

Answer (score 5):

Note first of all that [GitHub](https://github.com/) is simply one of several online services for storing files that are version controlled with [Git](https://git-scm.com/).
Git is the program that actually tracks the changes and versions your files, and without going too in-depth on the internals, simply keeps track of different versions of a file.

When you make a change to a file, that change is saved, just as if the file was not under version control. When you close the application, your changes stay, just as if git was not present. Committing your changes simply saves a sort of "checkpoint" to git itself. This allows you to revert your changes to a previous commit, compare different versions, etc. Your commits are also saved if you exit out of the applications.

Essentially yes, commits are stored in a folder somewhere, however git is smart enough not to store lots of copies of your files at different points in time, but rather stores as little information as possible while still keeping a record of what was changed. The staging area is simply a place to decide which files you want git to track. When you go to commit files, only those that have been added to the staging area are committed to git. The rest still have their changes saved as normal, but since you did not tell git to care about them, they are ignored. You can see this by changing some files, adding only some of them to the staging area with `git add`, and then calling `git status`, which will inform you that some files have been stage for commit, while others are "modified" or "untracked" but will not be committed.

If you really want to poke around, you could try opening up the hidden `git` folder in your repository (prefixed with a `.` on Mac/Linux) to see how git stores the changes you have made.